# Why not directly draw a circle with a compass using $BC$ as the distance and $A$ as the center, and then get $AL$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In Euclid’s Elements proposition $I.1$, why not directly draw a circle with a compass using $BC $ as the distance and $A$ as the center, and then get $AL$?  Is Euclid’s method too complicated?

[image]

[Euclid’s Elements proposition $I.1$](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI2.html)

Comment: The kind of compass Euclid worked with collapsed if it was lifted from the page, so when you shift the point to A, the width of the opening is no longer the length of BC.

Comment: It was not until about Galileo's time that we began to have metal compasses (at least, dividers, used with maps). There is uncertainty, some ancient Greek words seem to refer to the Egyptians using long ropes, one end fixed, to draw arcs or measure segments.

Comment: " The compass is assumed to have no maximum or minimum radius, and is assumed to "collapse" when lifted from the page, so may not be directly used to transfer distances. (This is an unimportant restriction since, using a multi-step procedure, a distance can be transferred even with collapsing compass; "   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straightedge_and_compass_construction

Comment: @GerryMyerson If the radius is so difficult to control, how do you control the radius in the process of drawing a circle?

Comment: While you're drawing the circle, you're not lifting the compass from the paper. Pressure keeps it from collapsing. Try it!

Comment: @GerryMyerson Then, my compass does not leave the paper, drag the compass to A on the paper, and then draw a circle.  Can't this be done?

Comment: @WillJagy Then, my compass does not leave the paper, drag the compass to A on the paper, and then draw a circle. Can't this be done?

Comment: If it could be done, I imagine Euclid would have done it, netF.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Do you think it is impossible to pass distance like this?

Comment: See my previous comment.

Comment: In a closely-related question, why didn't Galois just use the root-finder in his calculator?

Comment: Euclid shows a means of copying a distance from one place to another, in Bk. 1 Prop.2. So from then on, you may suppose the compass to be a modern one which preserves its span when one leg is lifted -- because you may suppose distances to be copied using Bk. 1 Prop.2.  But this method is not available in Bk.1 Prop.1's method of constructing an equilateral triangle -- which needs to come before Euclid's distance-copying algorithm because the latter entails constructing an equilateral triangle.